# Beautiful Soup IMDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get the name of IMDB top movies . But I don't know how can I get the specifically movie names

Here is source code

```
<a href="/title/tt0111161/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&amp;pf_rd_p=e31d89dd-322d-4646-8962-327b42fe94b1&amp;pf_rd_r=XCFVE1SQVHJADWSSD8TG&amp;pf_rd_s=center-1&amp;pf_rd_t=15506&amp;pf_rd_i=top&amp;ref_=chttp_tt_1" title="Frank Darabont (dir.), Tim Robbins, Morgan Freeman">The Shawshank Redemption</a>
```

and here is my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

file = open("text-txt-file.txt", "w") 
imdburl1 = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"

r = requests.get(imdburl1)

soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")

data = soup.find_all("table", {"class":"chart full-width"})

movietable = (data[0].contents) [len(data[0].contents) - 2]

movietable = movietable.find_all("tr")

for i in movietable:
    filmtitles = i.find_all("td", {"class":"titleColumn"})
    for j in filmtitles:
        moviename = j.find_all("a")
        print() # what to do ????

input()
```

Answer (score 1):

*Run loop on `moviename` then get the `title`*

```
    for title in moviename:
        print(title.get('title'))  # what to do ????
```

---

*full code*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

file = open("text-txt-file.txt", "w")
imdburl1 = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top"

r = requests.get(imdburl1)

soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")

data = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "chart full-width"})

movietable = (data[0].contents)[len(data[0].contents) - 2]

movietable = movietable.find_all("tr")

for i in movietable:
    filmtitles = i.find_all("td", {"class": "titleColumn"})
    for j in filmtitles:
        moviename = j.find_all("a")
        for title in moviename:
            print(title.get('title'))  # what to do ????
```

---

> [image]